# Using decorators to set initial class property value

Tags: javascript, decorator

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I can (and *if* I can) use a [decorator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) to set a default value on a class property. For example, something like:

```
const defaultValue = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'Example value' : null

class Foo {
  constructor () {
      this.bar = null
  }

  @default bar
}

const item = new Foo()

console.log(item.bar) // Should return null or 'Example value' depending on outside factors.
```

The sample above is obviously missing the declaration of the decorator `@default`, because that's what I don't know how to do.

My example above is simplified, in reality I will be using localstorage to check if there is a value that can be loaded from e previous user session. If not, the decorator should not change anything.

Now - I've tried to do this, but I couldn't figure out how to use a decorator to return a value, or if it's even possible at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: I'm using this in a [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/) project, which is why I'm keen an continuing with ES.Next decorators.

Comment: notice that it is a proposal, therefore not part of ES6 thus not valid JS. Neither are property declaration directly in a class body.

Comment: Decorators are in flux. Do you want to try to do this with the latest version of the proposal, or with the previously-popular "legacy" version common in some areas (such as React development)?

Comment: @mpm Right, sorry about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm aware, I've updated the question with information regarding MobX which I'm using for this particular case. I'm using decorators as they are widely used there (though I'm aware that it's in flux)

Comment: The clarification doesn't really clarify. I *think* MobX uses legacy decorators, but...

Comment: Well, I linked to the spec, doesn't that make it clear? I wasn't aware there were different versions, but if we assume I'm talking about the decorator spec that I've linked to?